# Angular/Jasmine - How do I test an directive that emits an event after a keyboard event?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I wrote a directive to capture escape key presses to close a modal screen:

```ts
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appEscapeKeydown]'
})
export class EscapeKeydownDirective {
  @Output() escapeKeydown = new EventEmitter<KeyboardEvent>();

  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event'])
  onKeyDownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.escapeKeydown.emit(event);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```html
<div appEscapeKeydown (escapeKeydown)="doSomething()">
...
```

It works well for my use cases.

When I tried to write some unit test (jasmine/karma), it wouldn't trigger the keydown handler:

```ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { EscapeKeydownDirective } from './escape-keydown.directive';

describe('EscapeKeydownDirective', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HostComponent>;
  let component: HTMLDivElement;
  let directive: EscapeKeydownDirective;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        EscapeKeydownDirective,
        HostComponent,
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HostComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div')).nativeElement;
    directive = fixture.componentInstance.directive as EscapeKeydownDirective;
  });

  it('should call foo if user presses escape key', () => {
    spyOn(directive, 'onKeyDownHandler');
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.calledFoo).toBeFalse();

    component.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Escape' }));

    expect(directive.onKeyDownHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.calledFoo).toBeTrue();

  });
});


@Component({
  template: `
    <div appEscapeKeydown (escapeKeydown)="foo()"></div>
  `
})
class HostComponent {
  @ViewChild(EscapeKeydownDirective) directive?: EscapeKeydownDirective;
  calledFoo = false;

  foo() {
    this.calledFoo = true;
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me find what I'm doing wrong, or tell me if there's a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in a asynchronous code, you must let angular resolve all the events. In that case, you can use:

`fixture.detectChange` or `await fixture.whenStable();` before the expect.

Also, I recommend to use the AAA patern for lisibility (Arrange, Act, Assert)

For the AAA patern, it's only to have a better view on the tests. like this:

```
  it('should call foo if user presses escape key', () => {
    // Arrange
    spyOn(directive, 'onKeyDownHandler');
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.calledFoo).toBeFalse();
   
    // Act
    component.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Escape' }));

    // Assert
    fixture.detectChange();
    expect(directive.onKeyDownHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.calledFoo).toBeTrue();

  });
});
```

Comment: Neither method worked :/ I tried to use the AAA pattern, what makes my code not in conformity with it? the expectation below the spyOn?